Image Field in Django forms is not working
html file:
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Sign Up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method = "post", action = "/signup/",enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
            <button type = "submit", name = "save" >Save</button>
            <button onclick="location.href = '/'">Home</button>
            {% if usernameExists %}
                <h3> Username already exists!</h3>
            {% elif not passwordConfirmed %}
                <h3>Passwords do not match!</h3>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

urls.py:

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index,name = "index"),
    path("signup/",views.signup,name = "signup"),
    path("login/",views.login,name = "login"),
]
urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root =settings.MEDIA_ROOT )

settings.py:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

forms.py:
class SignUp(forms.Form):
    is_doctor = forms.BooleanField(label = "Are you a doctor?",required=False)
    f_name = forms.CharField(label = "First Name", max_length=200)
    l_name = forms.CharField(label="Last Name",max_length=200)
    username = forms.CharField(label = "Username",max_length = 100)
    email = forms.CharField(label = "Email",max_length=200)
    profile_pic = forms.FileField(label= "Profile Picture", widget = forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(label ="Password",max_length=200)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label = "Confirm Password",max_length=200)
    address = forms.CharField(label="Address",max_length = 400)

views.py:
form = SignUp(response.POST,response.FILES)
In the html file I have the attribute: enctype="multipart/form-data"
I cannot understaNd what else I need to do. I  have read so many docs and watched so many videos. They're all saying the same thing.
